# Laravel command php artisan serve showing Directory does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I have installed Lavarel on my ubuntu system by going through [this](http://phpraxis.wordpress.com/2014/07/04/getting-started-with-laravel-4-on-ubuntu-installation-and-configuration/) link. After all the steps I can see the laravel default page(You have arrived). I came to know about the laravel command tool. So inside laravel folder from command tool(terminal) I tried

```
php artisan serve
```

and it showed me like this

```
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000
Directory  does not exist.
```

When I used `http://localhost:8000` from the browser it showed me like This webpage is not available. So can someone tell me how to solve this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall it and skip the part when you remove public folder. It's a good security feature to have your public folder separated from your application code.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused when Laravel cannot find `public/index.php`. You might need to update `boostrap/paths.php` to reflect your current public path.

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap/paths.php, change

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/public',
```

to

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../',
```

*(Assuming there's a good reason for butchering the base install, such as deploying on IIS)